# how to avoid re-rendering when passing the object into value of context.provider using React context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-class-based-component

In class component when we want to pass the object to the value of context provider using react context, we have a way to avoid re-rendering issue. Below are the codes

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      contextState: {
        count: 0,
        increment: this.increment
      }
    };
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({
      contextState: {
        ...this.state.contextState,
        count: this.state.contextState.count + 1
      }
    });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CountContext.Provider value={this.state.contextState}>
        <div style={styles}>
          <input name="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChange} />
          <div>Count: {this.state.contextState.count}</div>
          <Container1 />
          <Container2 />
        </div>
      </CountContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

We put this.state.contextState to value of CountContext.Provider. So when user types anything in input element and will not cause `<Container1 />` and `<Container2 />` re-rendered. Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qqx1jqk8mj?file=/src/index.js:260-1105

I am tring to convert it into hooks. Here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-gauss-duk64?file=/src/index.js but the counter is not working properly. May I please know which part is wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hook component, you just need to use the functional setState approach.

`setContextState(prevState=>newState)`

In your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-shtern-g6oll?file=/src/index.js

```
  const [contextState, setContextState] = useState({
    count: 0,
    increment: () => {
      setContextState(prev=>({
        ...prev,
        count: prev.count + 1
      }));
    }
  });
```

The reason you need to do this is because the state value will never update because of the closure around it. `contextState.count` will always remain at 0 because it was the value when the state was originally set (`0`), and it won't change.